# Exception:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I am using vagrant and my database default configuration are as below(Cakephp-3):

```
'Datasources' => [ 
    'default' => [ 
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection', 
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql', 
        'persistent' => false, 
        'host' => 'localhost', 
        'username' => 'root', 
        'password' => 'root', 
        'database' => 'vom', 
        'encoding' => 'utf8', 
        'timezone' => 'UTC', 
        'flags' => [], 
        'cacheMetadata' => true, 
        'log' => false, 
        ... ... ...
```

My virtual-box ip = '192.168.33.10' I have changed `db-host` with my vagrant ip but seeing the same error when run the

```
command: cake migrations migrate
```

Comment: Please format your code in the question first and explain it properly.

Comment: do you set db password ad `root` try `''` blank

Comment: trying to set password=' '; but getting the same error